# Is there a way to automatically reload the list without avoiding a flash?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jframe

In practice, I need a way to automatically reload my Jlist from a mysql database, preventing it from flashing.

```
    JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    btnRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            BindList();
        }
    });
    btnRefresh.setBounds(199, 414, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnRefresh);
     setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setVisible(true);
 }



 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void BindList(){
     Connection con;
     Statement st;
     ResultSet rs;
     try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(link, Username, Password);
         st = con.createStatement();
         rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM groups");
         listModel.clear();
         while(rs.next()){
             listModel.addElement("<html>"+ rs.getString(2) + " | " + rs.getString(3) + "</html>");
         }
         con.close();
     }catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }

 }
```

this is my code... how i can add autoreload?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: I have never noticed problems. A couple of suggestions. 1) maybe the problem is the HTML, which can take longer to render. Try just using a normal text string to see if you still have a problem. 2) Instead of update the existing ListModel, Create a new ListModel, add the data to the model and then when the loop is finished, reset the model of the JList by using the setModel() method.

Comment: fair enough @camickr to mine "defence" i didn't do Java for a ages.. Also not sure what he meant with flashing (i assume he meant flicking) but it feels like a "double buffering" problem or possible disabled (`setDoubleBuffered(false)`) pretty sure your mentioned points will solve the problem better..